# Yii Onchange issue?

Tags: javascript, php, yii

I have two field in Yii. One is dropdown in which I have `roles types` dropdown and another is `designation` which is a textbox. I have a onchange in `role type` that when its value changes then in `designation` field value also changes like this:

```
  <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'user_role',$roleTypeList,array('onchange'=>'setdesignation'));?>
     <?php echo $form->textField($model, 'user_designation',array('class'=>'w200','maxlength'=>'255'));?>
                   
        
        <script>
        function setdesignation(){
        var foundText = false;
        $("#<?php echo CHtml::activeId($model,'user_role')?> option").each(function(){
        if(jQuery.trim(jQuery(this).text()) == jQuery('#<?php echo  CHtml::activeId($model,'user_designation');?>').val())){
        foundText = true;
        }
        
        });
        if(jQuery.trim(jQuery('#<?php echo CHtml::activeId($model,'role_designation');?>').val()) == '' ||(foundText && jQuery.trim(jQuery("#<?php echo CHtml::active($model,'user_role')?>").find('option:selected').val())!='')){ 
jQuery('#<?php echo CHtml::activeId($model,'user_designation');?>').val(jQuery("#<?php echo CHtml::activeId($model,'user_role')?>").find('option:selected').text())} return true;}
    
    </script>
```

This works fine as I change `role` in dropdown it changes `designation`. My role type array is like:

```
array(1=>'admin',2=>'finance',3=>'operation');
```

First time when my form loads `role type` `selected` `value` is `admin`. But this time `designation` field is `empty`. I want it should also has admin value.

If I defined it explicitly like `$model->user_designation = 'admin'`. Then `onchange` not work.

Comment: If you put '<?php ... ' (with single quotes) it might have issues, have you tried putting every <?php block inside " (double quotes)?